# ggplot2 wrong position of error bars over the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I've a problem. I use for my error bars the standard error (se). My error bars are far above my bars and I've tried already placing the ymin and ymax in ggplot itself, but with no effect.

My data frame looks like the following:

```
  ID variable        se
1 A  14.340695 0.7917790
2 B  32.506312 0.9092173
3 C  7.279953 0.0444325
```

And I used the following code:

```
df$variable=as.numeric(as.character(df$variable))
limits<-aes(ymin=df$variable - df$se, ymax=df$variable + df$se)
r<-ggplot(df, aes(x=ID, y=factor(variable), fill=variable)) 
r + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") + geom_errorbar(limits)
```

I don't know why the position of the error_bars ends up so much higher than the bars itself.

I would appriciate your help, many thanks!

Comment: Do not use `df$` within `aes`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but I'm interested in why not using it. I'm new to ggplot2. Could you @Roland plz explain it to me?

Comment: Because when the plot is created the variables specified in `aes` are evaluated within the data.frame passed to the `data` argument of `ggplot` or the geom. If you use `df$` it takes them from the data.frame outside the plotting code. And sometimes ggplot2 reorders the data. As a result the variables evaluated with the data.frame passed to ggplot2 and those from outside ggplot2 don't line up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something with  setting y as factor. If you remove it, it works:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ID, y=variable, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=variable-se, ymax=variable+se))
```